# Cross apply two list, return same modified object

Tags: c#, linq

I was trying to make all combination(cross apply) between two list and assign second list's values to first list's objects(select modified objects from first list). Although right now I have created and retured anonymous type like below

```cs
select new {user = u, policy = p}
```

or can also return new object as below

```cs
return new testClass() { policyId = pid, userId = uid.userId };
```

I did try to pass first and second objects in different function then assign value of second object in first object then return first object.

But I want to understand what I'm doing wrong and why policyId for all result object is last value of second list.

```cs
public class testClass
{
    public int userId;
    public int policyId;
}
var users = new List<testClass> { new testClass { userId = 1 }, 
                                  new testClass { userId = 2 } };
var policies = new List<int> { 11, 22 };

var result = (from u in users
                from p in policies
                select new Func<testClass, int, testClass>((uid, pid) =>
                {
                    uid.policyId = pid;
                    return u;
                })(u, p)).ToList();
```

Problem with above code is it generates unexpected result.

Expected

```
1,11<br/>
2,11<br/>
1,22<br/>
2,22<br/>
<br/>
```

Actual

```
1,22<br/>
2,22<br/>
1,22<br/>
2,22<br/>
```

Comment: Youre updating the original user because of `uid.policyId = pid`; only the last update sticks.

Comment: In the process, first you are assigning 11 to userId 1 and then 22 to the same user 1 and so on. Last update is winning.

Comment: Thanks @CetinBasoz and Caramiriel. I literally missed this. I just wanted to understand this behavior.

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
    var query = from x in policies
            from y in users
                    select new { y.userId, x };
  var items = query.ToList();
```

Comment: additional info, `query.OrderBy(c => c.y).ToList()` to get the `expected` of OP